# Qt style - transparent border

Tags: css, qt, pyqt

```
widget.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red")
```

makes red border.

How can I make transparent border?
So that when I add red border, widget size stays the same.

Comment: `1px solid transparent`?

Comment: Random guess: did you try `transparent` in place of `red`?

Comment: heh, did not expected that it is possible after html's css. It works. Answer it for closing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Random guess: did you try transparent
>   in place of red? – thirtydot

Based on the fact that `transparent` works in "normal CSS", I guessed that it might work in Qt.

And it does work :)